# Bootstrap4 adding scrollbar to div

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using [stacked pills](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#stacked-pills) inside a `div`. The problem is, sometimes the `div` contains a lot of pills. How can I add a scrollbar for it?

```
<div class="row col-md-2">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can I add a class for the div to make stacked pills scrollable?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes, It is possible,
Just add a class like `anyclass`
and give some CSS style. [Live](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/we2qwxa6/2/)

```
.anyClass {
  height:150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
.anyClass {
  height:150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class=" col-md-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked anyClass">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li><li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li><li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li><li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li><li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to give height which is equal to height of screen?

Comment: @MuhammadDanish Yes, you can use `height: 100vh` or if you have top bar or menu then also use `height: calc(100vh - 100px)` NB: 100px was example

Answer (score 7):

Use the `overflow-y: scroll` property on the element that contains the elements.

The `overflow-y` property specifies whether to clip the content, add a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element, when it overflows at the top and bottom edges.

Sometimes it is interesting to place a height for the element next to the overflow-y property, as in the example below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="height: 250px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.Scroll {
  height:600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Smooth Scroll</h1>

<div class="Scroll">
  <div class="main" id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Click on the link to see the "smooth" scrolling effect.</p>
    <p>Note: Remove the scroll-behavior property to remove smooth scrolling.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Knowing how to write a paragraph is incredibly important. It’s a basic aspect of writing, and it is something that everyone should know how to do. There is a specific structure that you have to follow when you’re writing a paragraph. This structure helps make it easier for the reader to understand what is going on. Through writing good paragraphs, a person can communicate a lot better through their writing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="section3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Knowing how to write a paragraph is incredibly important. It’s a basic aspect of writing, and it is something that everyone should know how to do. There is a specific structure that you have to follow when you’re writing a paragraph. This structure helps make it easier for the reader to understand what is going on. Through writing good paragraphs, a person can communicate a lot better through their writing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="section4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <p>Knowing how to write a paragraph is incredibly important. It’s a basic aspect of writing, and it is something that everyone should know how to do. There is a specific structure that you have to follow when you’re writing a paragraph. This structure helps make it easier for the reader to understand what is going on. Through writing good paragraphs, a person can communicate a lot better through their writing.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main" id="section5">
    <h2>Section 5</h2>
    <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="section6">
    <h2>Section 6</h2>
    <p>Knowing how to write a paragraph is incredibly important. It’s a basic aspect of writing, and it is something that everyone should know how to do. There is a specific structure that you have to follow when you’re writing a paragraph. This structure helps make it easier for the reader to understand what is going on. Through writing good paragraphs, a person can communicate a lot better through their writing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="main" id="section7">
    <h2>Section 7</h2>
    <a href="#section1">Click Me to Smooth Scroll to Section 1 Above</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="overflow-auto p-3 mb-3 mb-md-0 mr-md-3 bg-light" style="max-width: 260px; max-height: 100px;">
        <strong>Column 0 </strong><br>
        <strong>Column 1</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 2</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 3</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 4</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 5</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 6</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 7</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 8</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 9</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 10</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 11</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 12</strong><br>
        <strong>Column 13</strong><br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class like `addScroll`

```
.addScroll {
  height:300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```